# Interactive Google Map with search functionality

Tags: google-maps

I found this website  http://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/map.html?locationIdentifier=REGION%5E93932 and I am very interested on its functionality, now I wanted that kind of stuff on my website where user can add entries and search entries through map. I am using wordpress and unable to find a plugin that can do that. I hope you guys to give me at least a tips or recommendations, any help is truly appreciated. Thanks a lot :).

Comment: Guys, i'm so sad, coz I am stuck with this, I can't move on.. I don't where to start.. 
here are the details.. I am creating a B&B website that offers free, featured, and premium listings. All the listing will be coming form a single form which is created using Formidable Pro http://formidablepro.com , and users must become a member to use the free listing and upgrade it to featured and premium. of course all entries has a location address included, and I want those addresses to be marked on my google map dynamically. My address field are Adress 1 - txtfield City / State - txtfield Country

Comment: i can display entries using the shortcode of each field using the custom display of formidable pro just like here in there demo http://demo.formidablepro.com/real-estate-listings, please view the code on how they displayed. any tip please.. do I have to do to manually or there is an easy way for me to be able to do that.. please help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have luck looking into this plugin however, implementation is not super easy, and I'm unsure about support, but the results for one of my projects has been great.

- Plugin Name: Location Marker Maps
- Plugin URI: http://adventesia.com/
- Description: Google maps with custom markers for single and multiple
  location maps. Create Locations in a Magic Field group and magically
  they are plotted on googlemaps.
- Version: 1.1
- Author: Sean Reichle
- Author URI: http://seanreichle.com
- License: MIT